# docker compose with multiple projects in different folders

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am experimenting with docker and trying to create a demo of everything working without having to commit anything yet. I have multiple git repos that have services within them. We clone all these projects into a central folder.

I want to create a new docker project that references the individual dockerfiles - this way I can build up my demo without having to re-structure everything - e.g.

```
Projects/
├── orchestratorService/
│   └── Dockerfile
├── microserviceB/
│   └── Dockerfile
└── microserviceC/
|   └── Dockerfile
└── docker/
    └── dockercompose.yaml
```

My problem is that the dockercompose file will only recognise things within the same folder. This means it can't "see" the other folders in the Projects/ directory.

I don't want to move the dockercompose file into Projects/ as that folder is not part of a repo.

Is there any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

let me try to answer your question as I understand
I think your question is straight forward it is possible to do as u said so structure your docker compose file as the following

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  MicroServiceA:
    build:
      context: MicroServiceA
  MicroServiceB:
    build:
      context: MicroServiceB
.
.
.
.
```

when you give context the folder name it access docker file directly

write me more explanation if I miss your question

Comment: I think you are correct. For some reason I thought the projects had to be in the same folder as the docker-compose file. I now realise I can do something like the following, where the docker-compose file is referencing files that are in sibling folders.
```
services;
  microserviceA:
    build: ../microserviceA/.
  microserviceB:
    build: ../microserviceB/.
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I thought the projects had to be in the same folder as the docker-compose file. I now realise I can do something like the following, where the docker-compose file is referencing files that are in sibling folders.

```
services;
  microserviceA:
    build: ../microserviceA/.
  microserviceB:
    build: ../microserviceB/.
```